# Why does SHA-256 have any to do with scrypt?

Tags: key-derivation, sha-256, passwords, password-hashing

I was reading the [Wikipedia page for scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) because I wanted to learn more about it and I came across their pseudocode for the algorithm. What confused me was the following line:
[image]

I don't understand why having (what I assume to be) an output length of 32 bytes would make it in any way associated with SHA-256. Yes, they would have the same output size but why does it associate it with it in any other way?

Thanks in advance for any explanations.

Comment: I think this is just an example, and depending on the Hash function used, it may change.

Comment: The hash function being what? Isn't scrypt the hash function itself?

Comment: @DarcySutton scrypt uses PBKDF2 internally, which uses HMAC, which uses a hash function like SHA-256. You can see 'PBKDF2' and 'HMAC-SHA256' in the diagram. It's perhaps easier to think of scrypt as a fancy wrapper that does extra mixing.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 thanks for explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't scrypt the hash function itself?

No. [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) is not a hash function as [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) is a hash function. Depending on who speaks, scrypt is a [password-based | memory-hard | purposely slow] [[key] [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)] | [function | hash]. The main difference with a standard hash is that scrypt has parameters `CostFactor`, `BlockSizeFactor`, `ParallelizationFactor` controlling the difficulty of computing the function. Also there are two data inputs `Passphrase` and `Salt` rather than one in a standard hash, and a parameter `DesiredKeyLen` controlling the output size. And further parameters.

Internally, scrypt uses [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)-with-a-low-number-of-rounds as a building block, with PBKDF2 using the [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) construction, with HMAC using a (typically [Merkle–Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction)) hash such as (typically) [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256).

> Why would having hLen of 32 bytes make scrypt in any way associated with SHA-256?

The `hLen` parameter of scrypt is the output width (in bytes) of the standard hash used by HMAC, used by PBKDF2-with-a-low-number-of-rounds, used by scrypt. Only when `hLen` is 32 can SHA-256 be used as the standard hash.

With `hLen` set to 64, the hash can be changed to e.g. SHA-512, and that increases the security of HMAC, and of PBKDF2-with-a-low-number-of-rounds. Typically on 64-bit machines that increases the speed of these for large input (or/and output for PBKDF2), and of scrypt with a large `DesiredKeyLen` (or/and large input). That also increases the security of scrypt from some standpoint, but *not* (at least, not much) from the standpoint that typically motivates the use of scrypt, which is [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) (that is giving some level of protection against search of a password/passphrase by brute force: [password cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking)).

---

Note: we typically use

- Some standard hash (SHA-256, SHA-512, [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3), [Blake2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)#BLAKE2)) to make a small, fixed-size representative of some message, in a public manner.
- a [Mask Generation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_generation_function) such as [MGF1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_generation_function#MGF1) when we need a hash with arbitrarilly wide output (and perhaps add a parameter in addition to the message).
- HMAC or SHA-3 for a keyed hash/[MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). The main functional difference with a hash is that there is a secret key.
- [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) or PBKDF2-with-a-low-number-of-rounds for a fast key derivation function, when we need to add a parameter in addition to the message (e.g. to turn a [Diffie–Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) shared secret into multiple session keys), and/or perhaps extend the width of the result. This sort of combines the features of the above two extensions of standard hashes.
- scrypt or [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) as a purposely-slow key derivation function for key stretching, e.g. for construction of a password hash/token for access control. At equal computing time, scrypt and Argon2 are vastly superior to PBKDF2 from the standpoint of key stretching. The only two sound reasons I can discern to use PBKDF2 for that purpose are compatibility with legacy software, and purposely weakening a new system against password search.